# How to collapse a row in RDLC rather than just hide it?

Tags: rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have an RDLC report showing a table.
A certain row in this table should not appear in some conditions apply.
I was able to set the Hidden property to false using an expression if these conditions apply.

The problem is that, though hidden, the row is still taking place in the table, i.e. it is not collapsed.

How can  I collapse it rather than simply hide it?

I am using RDLC with report viewer 2010 SP1

Comment: Mark the correct answer for others to find. The second one with the toggle item does the trick. Setting hidden as the marked answer suggest does not work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this solution

set Hidden property to True or False

```
= (Fields!UserName.Value.ToString() = "")
```

Also check [expression examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#Properties)

Hope this answer help you.

Comment: I have seen this solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627647/hide-a-tablerow-in-a-net-rdlc-report-if-the-field-represented-in-the-row-is-empt   but the point is not setting hidden to true. it is to collapse the row so it does not occupy any space in the table.

Comment: You just need to set the hidden property true or false and the required line needed to be set it will work.

Comment: This not work, the correct answer is from @Crowcoder

Comment: yah scroll down for the correct answer of @Crowcoder

Answer (score 25):

Despite the insistance that their solution works, the Hidden property still makes the row take up space. No big deal if it is the last row, but when it is between rows it can be a big deal. And Can Shrink is no help either.
The solution to collapse the row is the right-click the row header and select Row Visibility..., then enter the expression that will evaluate to true or false.

Comment: Row visibility worked for me, this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that CanShrink is set to true.