# Removing table row instead of hiding in rdlc reports

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

i want to remove row if row data is less then 1.when i set hidden to false using following expression it hide row but still taking its space.

[image]

```
=IIF(Fields!PartuclarValue.Value<1,true,false)
```

**How can i remove the row complete so it does not take any space in report**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15883208/2224701

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting visibility property for table cells, then row will still appear in the report. Instead, set row visibility based on your condition - right click on row header and select "Row Visibility" option:

[image]